# C# simple regexp pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a bit lost on C# regexp, I want to replace:

> [img:32uyjtdu]

With

```
<img src="
```

The `32uyjtdu` is any number of chars.

Comment: You want to replace it with an incomplete HTML tag?

Comment: Do you mean replace it with `<img src="32uyjtdu" />` ?

Comment: @Chaos, yes, I'm imorting some forum data to a new forum and I have to reformat all forum codes

Comment: @Matt no it's ok I'll do the end tag the same way to close it

Comment: most replies are dead wrong then :)

Comment: @Carlo V. Dango yes all of the replies are incorrect with that added information

Comment: Just a note: It's bad practice to do by RegEx, that, which can be done by simple string replaces in less computing time and less cpu cycles. `string.Replace("[img:", "<img src=\""); string.Replace("]", "\"/>");` Also you're missing an `alt` attribute, which is required.

Comment: @Bazz, it's a one off cost, I'm not worried about performance at all.  Also, the old forum has no alt information so I can't really generate any.  I don't see why the answers are wrong, I've run it and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code replaces any occurrence of `[img:32uyjtdu]` (where `32uyjtdu` stands for a sequence of lowercase letters and digits of arbitrary length) with `<img src="`:

```
var input = "Foo bar [img:32uyjtdu] baz qux";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[img:([a-z0-9]*)\]", @"<img src=""");

//  result == "Foo bar <img src=\" baz qux"
```

Comment: this would match no numbers too. ie [img:]

Comment: Problem formulation has now been altered to represent the answer :)

Comment: You'll see that it's wrong if you do the replace as suggested above. Your image name is NOT put inside of your IMG tag as you wanted. Only the first half of the tag is generated. See my answer..

Answer (score 3):

This will match the input string you provided:

```
\[img\:[0-9a-zA-Z]+\]
```

Here's a cool resource to test your regexes:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture your image name in a group called `name` and use it to do a proper replace

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\[(img:(?<name>[^]]*)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
r.Replace(text, @"<img src="""${name}"">");
```

Comment: I liked that ${name}; didn't know it worked by name in a replace text as well. Much better then just $1 :)

Comment: Lol, I bet it is, but I've never ran across that section, even though I've been doing regexes for quite some years :) Always nice to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? Not sure what you want to do...

```
var xxx = "xxxxxxx [img:32uyjtdu] xxxxxxx";

var result = Regex.Replace(xxx, @"\[img\:([a-z0-9]+)\]",
    (m) =>
    {
        // do your thing here...
        return String.Format("<img alt='' src='{0}' />", m.Groups[1].Value);
    },
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
\[img:[0-9a-zA-Z]+?\]
```

This will match any number of characters (a-z, A-Z) and numbers after 'img:'

Comment: "The `32uyjtdu` is _any number_ of chars." Emphasis of 'any number' is my own.

Comment: @GrantThomas It is for *any* number. See documentation + means "one or more of the previous" and +? means that "one or more of the previous" as few times as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A nice tool to test your Regexes is this by [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/csharpregexdemo.zip)

In this case, you'd just do

> \[img\:(?<img>[^\]]+)\]

extract the group 'img' and use that to create your new image tag.

[Edit]

The replacement text would be

> <img src="$1" />

or

> <img src="${img}" />

Comment: LOL why did you steal my solution with the named parameter? :)

Comment: I found it to be a more elegant way of replacing, so I added yours. I left you a comment & voted up because I liked it :)

Answer (score 1):

You would use Regex.Replace with the pattern [img\:([0-9A-Za-z]+)\

```
Regex.Replace("[img:32uyjtdu]", "\[img\:([0-9A-Za-z]+)\", "<img src=\"");
```

I like to use www.regexpal.com to test my regexs. It does searching and matching as you put in the regex so the feedback is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this regexp is what you need.

```
\[img:[^\]]*\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(" xx    [img:32uyjtdu]  abc ",
                             @"(.*)(\[img:.*?\])(.*)",
                              "$1<img src=\"$3\">");
```

`result` string contains your output text:

`xx    <img src="  abc ">`

The question is very vague.. precise expected answer sample has not been provided.